# Installation of wifi driver stops

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am installing the drivers for the wifi on the macbook on which I recently installed Ubuntu through the **Software & Updates** menu under the **Additional drivers** tab. When I choose the driver and press *apply changes* the progress bar halts while it says *applying changes*.

I have tried unmounting and mounting the USB I am installing it from. As well as restarting my computer. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a Broadcom Wireless Card (BCMxxxx). You can check for the same using

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

To install the Broadcom drivers via the Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source dkms
```

Comment: Thanks. But when i try to install it, it says the following:

 

"Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter"



I have ubuntu on an USB-stick not a CD-rom. How do i tell it to get it from the USB-stick instead?

Comment: Open 'Software Sources' and uncheck the checkbox 'CDROM with Ubuntu'

Comment: Remove the media used for installation (ie USB Drive, CD) if you have already installed Ubuntu